# CSS - Have Image Move With Centered Text-Align Input Text

Tags: html, css

I have an text input with the following HTML:

```
<span>
    &#9997;
</span>
<input type="text">
```

and the corresponding CSS:

```
input{
    text-align: center;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

The input element should blend seamlessly into its background with only the HTML icon indicating that it is indeed an input.  The HTML icon will remain in a static position with the current mark-up as new text is added into the input.

Is there anyway to have my HTML icon start right to the left of the first letter and have it gradually move toward the left as the left boundary of the text string pushes in the same direction?

[Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/vn0vsk04/)

Comment: can you add some image as to what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Yeah, its not clear what you're asking

Answer (score 5):

If you're ok with contenteditable you could try this:

```css
span{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
span::before {
  content: '\270D';
}
```

```html
 <span contenteditable='true'></span>
```

Comment: I was just reading up on contenteditable, should it be `contenteditable="true"` ? [contenteditable @ mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable) As it is it works fine for me in FF.

Comment: @HastigZusammenstellen [the presence of a boolean attribute represents the true value](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/semantics.html#boolean) , so `contenteditable="true"` is equivalent to `contenteditable`

Comment: I'm half asleep and could very well be reading it wrong but what I'm getting from [w3: Keywords and enumerated attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/semantics.html#keywords) is because `contenteditable` has three options, the third being `=""` that makes it technically not a boolean (even though `=""` is the same as false) Also w3 validator doesn't like `<span contenteditable></span>` but passes `<span contenteditable="true"></span>`

Comment: @HastigZusammenstellen I've always assumed `contenteditable` to be a boolean attribute (in fact the browsers I use support it as boolean), but the spec say it's not so you're right ....

Comment: I think it's just one of those technical things that will never matter. I read a bit more on it cuz contenteditable is new to me. (I can replace textarea with it in a bunch of places.) [w3: contenteditable](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/editing.html#contenteditable) - ff and chrome don't seem to mind how its used.

Answer (score 1):

A possible but imperfect (needs lots of work) idea using jquery.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/m6v8Lps7/2/)

```js
$('input').bind('keypress', function(e) {
 var tester = $(this).val().length;
  var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
  var currentWidth = $('input').css('width').slice(0, -2);
  var currentWidthParsed = parseInt(currentWidth, 10);
  if(code == 8) {
    var newWidth = (currentWidthParsed - 8) + 'px'
    $('input').css('width', newWidth);
 } else {
    var newWidth = (currentWidthParsed + 8) + 'px'
    $('input').css('width', newWidth);
 }
});
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
input{
    text-align: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 100px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>
  &#9997;
</span>
<input type="text">
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know you can't have dynamic width of inputs with something like width: auto. In that case you could have a wrapper with fixed with and a text-align right.

So I would say the only possibility is to have that icon inside the value of the input (if it may exist as UTF-8 icon) and then strip it out when processing the value. But of course this would seem dirty.